# android italic typeface

Tags: android, fonts

I try to display italic text in a textview. 
I use the method TypeFace.defaultFromstyle(TypeFace.ITALIC) but it doesn't work, the style of the text is not set to italic. 
If i call the getStyle() method on the return of defaultFromstyle() it returns 0.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 20):

Use `setTypeface(Typeface)` from the Java code or `android:textStyle` from the XML layout. They should do the trick, if you want all your text to be italic.

Edit:
In that case, I would think that your font doesn't have italic style, by default. From the documentation of the `setTypeface(Typeface)` method:

*Sets the typeface and style in which the text should be displayed. Note that not all Typeface families actually have bold and italic variants, so you may need to use `setTypeface(Typeface, int)` to get the appearance that you actually want.*

Do you use custom font? Try

```
mTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC), Typeface.ITALIC)
```

Comment: It's exactly what I do. 
Here is my code : myTextView.setTypeface(TypeFace.defaultFromstyle(TypeFace.ITALIC));
but it doesn't work.
Nb: if I use TypeFace.BOLD, all it's OK.

Comment: Yes ! It's works, but I don't understand why... I use custom font which sould have italic variant !

Answer (score 2):

This should be all:

```
   textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
   textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
   textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on TextView ...

public void setTypeface (Typeface tf, int style)
Since: API Level 1

Sets the typeface and style in which the text should be displayed, and ***turns on the fake bold and italic bits in the Paint if the Typeface that you provided does not have all the bits in the style that you specified.***