# Samsung devices supporting setTypeface(Typeface.Italic)?

Tags: android, typeface, italic

I have in application that makes use of a custom View component that drawas some text onto the screen via Paint/Canvas.

I am using the following code (before I call canvas.drawText()) to make my text Italic:

```
mPaintText.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC));
```

This works on Samsung Galaxy Nexus. But on Samsung Epic 4g (galaxy S), Samsung Epic Touch (Galaxy SII), and Samsung Transform ultra my text is still non-italic.

Does anyone know why some of these samsung devices wouldn't support setting italic text that way? I know the devices are capable of rendering the italic text because if I have a TextView I can use either

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i>sometext</i>");
```

in java or

```
android:textStyle="italic"
```

in layout.xml and my text appears italic.

Does anyone know of another way that I can set the drawText() method of canvas to draw the text italicized that might work on these devices?

**EDIT:**

Here is a list of some ways I've tried it with their outcome in comments after. Turns out SERIF seems to be the only font that it works on.

```
mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.ITALIC) //Nothing
mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, Typeface.ITALIC) //Nothing
mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.ITALIC) //omg it is italic...But serifs look gross.
mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.ITALIC) //Nothing
mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.ITALIC) //Changes font, but still no italic.
mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC) //Bold but no italic
```

**EDIT AGAIN:** To make this function I ended up adding the italic version of the roboto font to my assets folder and applied it as a font. I'd still be interested if anyone ever finds a way to get it working without adding it this way.

Comment: What typeface are you using that is giving you this effect?

Comment: Whatever comes stock on the respective devices, I haven't changed the font.

Comment: This thread could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487333/android-italic-typeface

Comment: Try passing direct values to the `setTypeface` method..

Comment: Just for your info, my Galaxy SII has now been upgraded to 4.0.3 and  paint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC)) comes up OK in italic.

Comment: add a custom *NICE* font to ur assets and use setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC), Typeface.ITALIC)! And remember! it should be a NICE LOOKING font

Comment: I ended up adding the italic version of the system font to my assets.

Comment: On my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, the setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC)) solution doesn't work for me...

Comment: @thomaus right, that is the same issue I was facing. I never found a way to solve it really. I just ended up getting a copy of the italic system font and adding it to my application assets, and set my font to it.

Comment: Thanks FoamyGuy, and would you mind providing me the way to do that (= copy the italic system font, adding it to the app assets and set the font to it)?

Comment: This thread coule be useful too -> http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=210630

Answer (score 2):

It may be that your Samsung device does not have a native italics version of the desired font installed. You may have to force the system to create the italics-style font synthetically. Try:

> `tv.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC),` **`Typeface.ITALIC`**`);`

**EDIT**

Instead of `defaultFromStyle`, try to use `Typeface.create (Typeface family, int style)` (documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#create(java.lang.String,int))).

Comment: But I am trying to apply it to text drawn with Canvas / Paint objects. And Paint.setTypeface() only accepts one argument, not two...

Comment: Just tested lots of the possible permutations of inputs to .create() results have been added to question.

Comment: Could be a bug in Samsung's Android implementation... which OS version is this?

Comment: Transform and Epic Touch(Galaxy S2) = 2.3.4, Regular Epic (Galaxy S) = 2.3.6

Answer (score 1):

Try passing direct values to the `setTypeFace` api till you find the right one. If italicizing   is working through other methods then there could be some problem in constant definitions in `TypeFace` class (in those builds).

```
mPaintText.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(0)); // then 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: If I start changing the values isn't that going to break it on the device that it does work on? (Galaxy Nexus)

Comment: just for investigation sake try it and see.. atleast you'll know the problem root.. we can think of a solution then..

Comment: Devices are at work, will try tomorrow. I found something that works but is not ideal. I found a copy of the italic system font and included it with my project, if I set the typeface to that file in my assets it appears correctly on the screen on the devices in question.

Comment: Did you get the root of the problem..?

Comment: nope, I tried subbing in several raw int values, but got nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug from Samsung and the best solution is, as FomayGuy said, to add the italic version of the system font to the assets.

The official Roboto Android font is available [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html).

Answer (score 0):

We need to check whether a default font supports an ITALIC mode. We do it by creating a temporal TextView object and measuring its width in both modes (NORMAL and ITALIC). If their widths are different, then it means an ITALIC mode is supported. Otherwise, a default font doesn't support it and we have to use setTextSkewX() method to skew a text.

```
    mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.ITALIC));

    // check whether a font supports an italic mode, returns false if it does't
    if (!supportItalicMode(this, Typeface.DEFAULT))
    {
        paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
    }



private boolean supportItalicMode(Context context, Typeface typeFace)
{
    Typeface tfNormal = Typeface.create(typeFace, Typeface.NORMAL);
    Typeface tfItalic = Typeface.create(typeFace, Typeface.ITALIC);

    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText("Some sample text to check whether a font supports an italic mode");

    textView.setTypeface(tfNormal);
    textView.measure(0, 0);
    int normalFontStyleSize = textView.getMeasuredWidth();

    textView.setTypeface(tfItalic);
    textView.measure(0, 0);
    int italicFontStyleSize = textView.getMeasuredWidth();

    return (normalFontStyleSize != italicFontStyleSize);
}
```