# Italic text not working on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, textview, galaxy-tab, italic

I don't why but my application doesn't show the TextView in italic on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (while it is working correctly on a Nexus 7 tablet for instance).

My code :

```
<style name="MyTheme.GeneralRedDate">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
</style>
```

Of course I already tried to put italic instead of bold|italic and it doesn't work neither.

**EDIT**
It seems that this thread is the same : [Samsung devices supporting setTypeface(Typeface.Italic)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420077/samsung-devices-supporting-settypefacetypeface-italic)

Comment: What happens if you take a simple TextView and set the `textStyle` to `bold|italic` directly from the layout?

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't work neither.

Comment: This sounds very odd to me; it would suggest that Samsung for some reason modified Android's TextView class to override or ignore `textStyle`. This would be evident in many applications and I haven't seen this on my own Galaxy Tab 2 7" before. I would suggest making a minimum working example to make sure there isn't just something wrong with your style declaration. (Perhaps you're targeting a different device class?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug from Samsung and the best solution is, as FomayGuy said, to add the italic version of the system font to the assets.

The official Roboto Android font is available [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html).